# linux + print linux version ( one single character as 5 or 6 .. etc )

Tags: linux, bash, perl, awk, sed

I created the following line , in order to verify Linux version ( as red hat 5.X or 4.X etc )

I think my line is too long and not so elegant

```
awk -F"release" '{print $2}'  /etc/redhat-release | awk '{print $1}' | sed s'/\./ /g' | awk '{print $1}'

5
```

Test:

```
$ LINUX_VERSION=` awk -F"release" '{print $2}'  /etc/redhat-release | awk '{print $1}' | sed s'/\./ /g' | awk '{print $1}' `
$ echo $LINUX_VERSION
5
```

maybe someone can give more elegant way to print the Linux version ?

```
$ more /etc/redhat-release 
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.4 (Tikanga)
```

Comment: I guess this file is mandatory file

Comment: See also: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/88647/17673

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't parse the file. Let the RedHat system version practices tell you what you want. See the documentation on `releasever` in `man yum.conf`.

Run `rpm -qf --qf '%{version}\n' /etc/redhat-release`

If you really need just the number (even in cases where the official release is `5Server` or `5Client`) then you need to pull that out with something like:

```
v=$(rpm -qf --qf '%{version}\n' /etc/redhat-release)

echo "${v%%[a-zA-Z]*}"
# or
echo "$v" | grep -o '^[0-9]*'
# or 
echo "$v" | tr -d 'a-zA-Z'
```

or anything else you like.

Comment: see what I get - rpm -qf --qf '%{version}\n' /etc/redhat-release
5Server   ( why server word also apears )

Comment: @maihabunash Because that's the version. RedHat does that. They can have all of 5, 5Server, and 5Client versions. I don't know why or what the differences are but they are distinct things in the RH world. Look at `http://ftp.redhat.com/pub/redhat/linux/enterprise/` for example.

Comment: but I need only the number ? ( can you update to see only the number ? )

Comment: Then you can strip it out of that with anything you like. `v=$(rpm ...); v=${v%%[a-zA-Z]*}` or `grep -o '^[0-9]'`, etc.

Comment: OK THX AND GMAR HATIMA TOVA ISANA TOVA

Comment: need to fix that V=$(rpm -qf --qf '%{version}\n' /etc/redhat-release)

Comment: Note you may need `grep -o '^[0-9]*'` because the release can contain two digits in the future.

Comment: +1 this seems the best solution to me, rather than parsing the file as the rest of us did. I didn't know about this `rpm -qf --qf`, will go through the `man yum.conf` to discover other juicy things!

Comment: @fedorqui The `yum.conf` man page reference was mostly just to point out that the package involved here is the one that yum uses to populate `$release` in its URLs as backup for the validity of this approach. (See `rpm -qf /etc/redhat-release` to get the full package name instead of just the version, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

This is what the `lsb_release` command is for.

```
$ lsb_release -sr
5.8
```

Or, with a bit of post-processing to just get the major version:

```
$ lsb_release -sr | perl -lnE '/(\d+)/ and say $1'
5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 awk -v RS='[. ]' '/[0-9]+/{print;exit}'
```

**Explanation**

- Change the record separator to whitespace or `.`. Whitespace to go through all the words easier; and `.` to separate the version in 2 records
- `Print` the record and `exit` when the record is a number

**Assumptions**

- The version is the first number found in the input